# Definition issue with limiting directions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, optimization

In Nocedal/Wright's *Numerical Optimization* (1999) in section 12.3 the notion of *feasible sequences* and related *limiting directions* are introduced as a starting point for the proof of the $1^{\text{st}}$-order necessary conditions (aka Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions) for $x$ being a solution of the constrained optimization problem 
$$ \begin{align}
& \min_{x} f(x) \\
s.t. \quad & c_i(x)=0 \quad i \in \mathcal{E}\\
& c_i(x) \ge 0 \quad i \in \mathcal{I \cap \mathcal{A}},
\end{align}$$
where $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of indices of equality constraints, $\mathcal{I}$ is the set of indices of inequality constraints and $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of indices of active constraints.

Feasible sequences $\{z_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ are defined as follows:

> $\{z_k\}$ is a feasible sequence that approaches $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $\stackrel{\text{def}}{\longleftrightarrow}$ (i) $\wedge$ (ii) $\wedge$ (iii). 
>   
>   (i) $(\forall k) \: z_k \neq x$. 
>   (ii) $\lim_\limits{k \rightarrow \infty} z_k = x$. 
>   (iii) $c(z_k) = 0$ for sufficiently large k,

where $c(x) = 0$ are constraints to the optimization problem.

The limiting direction $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ [of a feasible sequence] is introduced as a point such that

> $\lim_\limits{z_k \in \mathcal{S}_d} \frac{z_k - x}{||z_k - x||} \rightarrow d$,

where $\mathcal{S}_d$ is some subsequence of $\{ z_k \}$.

My question relates to the definition of the limiting direction: 
Shouldn't an equation sign be used instead:

$$\lim_\limits{z_k \in \mathcal{S}_d} \frac{z_k - x}{||z_k - x||} = d.$$

To my humble understanding the use of a '$\rightarrow$' binary operator requires the left-hand side to *converge* towards the expression on the right-hand side. But by chosing the appropriate subsequence $\mathcal{S}_d$ the limiting direction is given uniquely (or direction*s*, if there are many). Additionally, there might be feasible sequences such that the limiting direction does not converge at all.

---

**Edit**

What I could think of is that the author's intention might have been to define the limiting direction $d$ in the following fashion:

$$d \text{ is a limiting direction } \stackrel{\text{def}}{\longleftrightarrow} d \text{ is the limit value of }\frac{z_k - x}{||z_k - x||}, \: z_k \in \mathcal{S}_d,$$

since, formally speaking, the limit of a finite sequence is the last entry of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

[image][Example 2.12](http://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_06/Chapter2.pdf) illustrate the concepts of feasible sequences and limiting direction. I briefed you here.

$\min_{x\in R^2} {f(x)=x_1+x_2}$

subject to $h(x) = x_1^2+x_2^2-2=0$

consider a point $x^*=(-\sqrt{2}, 0)^T$ and a feasible sequence $x_k=(-\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{k^2}}, \frac{1}{k})^T$.

Thus we can see $ h(x_k) = 2; k = {1,2,3..}$ is moving along the circle. and $\lim_{k->\infty} x_k=x^*$.

Now let's enumerate: $k=1,2,3$: $x_1=(-1,1)^T$, $x_2=(-\sqrt{7}/2, 1/2)^T$, $(x_3 =-\sqrt{17}/3, 1/3)^T$. The limit of $x_k - x^*$ approach the tangent line at $x^*$, pointing to the direction of $x_2>0$. Note that the limiting direction is normalized, thus $d=(0,1)^T$.

PS: As for your question whether to use '$=$' or '$\rightarrow$', the author in above linked document uses exactly '$=$'. And it makes more sense to me as well!

Comment: could you please elaborate more. I did not get it.

Comment: @104078 thanks for allowing me to upload my sketching.