# Nocedal/Wright: Numerical Optimization, Lemma 12.3.(ii)

Tags: optimization, implicit-function-theorem, karush-kuhn-tucker

In the above given monograph (1999, 1E) the following parametrized system of equations $R:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is introduced:

$$ R(z,t) := 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
c(z) - tAd \\ Z^T (z - x^* - td)
\end{array}
\right] = 0,
 $$

where $t>0$ with $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}t_k = 0$.

(for a definition of the remaining symbols follow [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315728/definition-issue-with-limiting-directions) and [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327560/a-set-of-nonlinear-equations-their-gradients-a-nullspace-and-a-uniqueness-prop)).

**Question:**
How is this motivated?

I can see that $c(z) - tAd$ is some sort of reformulation of the feasible sequence's property to satisfy the constraints (for $z$ being sufficiently close to $x^*$). But what does $Z^T(z-x^*-td)$ refer to? My first attempt was to interpret is as a reformulation of the requirement of $z_k-x^*/||z_k-x^*||$ to approach $d$. But then I realized that $Z^T(z-x^*-td)=0$ does not imply $(z-x^*-td)=0$..

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I should have just read on (my own private Idaho error source no. 1):

The choice of the lower part of $R$ is motivated by the fact that $z = x^*$ and $t > 0$ never show up simultaneously. Since, by then,

$$ R(x^*, t) = t 
\underbrace{
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A \\ -Z^T
\end{array}
\right]}_{\bar{R}}
d = 0, $$

which would require, due to the regularity of $\bar{R}$, that $d=0$. Whereas $||d||=1$, by proposition, and the following holds:

$$||d||=1 \wedge (z \neq x^* \vee t = 0).$$